# How to obtain the Hadamard Transform of an image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 128x128 grascale image that i wish to find the Hadamard transform of with Normal Hadamard, sequency, and dyadic ordering.

```
imdata = imread('origim.png'); %Load image
new = rgb2gray(imdata); %Convert to 2D Grayscale

N = 128;
H = hadamard(N);                      % Hadamard matrix
y = fwht(new,N,'sequency') %Perform Fast-walsh-hadamard-transform with order 128
imshow(y); %Display image transform
```

I may be doing it wrong, however y should be the transformed image if i understand the matlab walch transform correctly. When i try runing it i get an error with `y = fwht(new,N,'sequency')`

Comment: "an error" - what error?  - also you create `H` and don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Before processing convert the image into double. Then put semicolon (;) at the end of y = fwht(new,N,'sequency'). Then you will get transformed image.
Just try the below code.

```
imdata = imread('peppers.png'); %Load image
new = rgb2gray(imdata); %Convert to 2D Grayscale
neww = im2double(new);
N = 128;
H = hadamard(N);                      % Hadamard matrix
y = fwht(neww,N,'sequency'); %Perform Fast-walsh-hadamard-transform with order 128
imshow(y); %Display image transform
```